# impedir que se pueda desinstalar app

Tags: android-studio

estoy realizando una app con Android studio con java y necesito hacer que no se pueda desinstalar esa aplicación una vez que este instalada o que solo la pueda borrar una serie de personas. 
Alguna solución??

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No es posible hacer algo así de forma legal y menos si tu intención es subirla a Google Play

Comment: Este post que he visto en internet (2016) habla de convertir la app de usuario a app de sistema para impedir que se desinstale incluso si se formatea. Decir como @solamente, no se si es legal o no. [Evitar desinstalar app](https://elandroidelibre.elespanol.com/2016/12/como-instalar-una-aplicacion-en-android-evitar-borrar.html)